# Changed variable value not available outside ajax request - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple fields in a form with same name, and I pass these values into ajax as;

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){

  var flag = 0;

  $('input[name="myfield"]').each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    var item = $.trim(current.val());
    if(item != ""){

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
        data: 'myitem='+item,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          if(result == "true"){
            flag++;
          }
          alert("stage1 = "+flag);//returns flag (1,2,3 etc)
        }
      });

    }
  });

  alert("stage2 = "+flag);//returns 0. But I need same value as on the flag above
});
```

The flag is set to count the number of valid items, and is collected for further use. But outside ajax block, its not available. How can I solve this?

Comment: simple answer it is asynchronous so you can't do it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

As the Ajax request is **asynchronous** then the `alert("stage2 = "+flag);`
Is called right after your ajax call without waiting for the response. That is why `flag=0`

Comment: Your are right, I've update my answer wich is not really a solution but might help to understand Ajax Call..

Answer (score 2):

Your `flag` variable is local variable which declared inside of click event handler. And it will not be visible to outside of event handler. So you should simply declare it outside of event handler. If you want to use it inside of click event itself you can make your ajax query `async:false` or create function and call it after ajax call done.

Comment: cant you see that everything is inside the click()

Comment: I saw. Read second part of my answer. Or create function inside of click event. And call this function inside of success of ajax.